# VMware Workstation on linux: guest direct access on unmounted drive [/dev/sdX (hfs+)]

Tags: linux, macos, vmware-workstation

Running OS X 10.11 guest on VMware Workstation 12 on Kubuntu Xenial host.

I need direct access to unmounted HDD [ /dev/sdX (hfs+) on host] for disk repair operations in VMware OS X 10.11 guest with pdisk.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have been very glad for any tip.

Anyway, finally I've got it.

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_add_ws.html

**Adding Raw Disks to a Virtual Machine**

Use the virtual machine settings editor (VM > Settings) to add a new raw disk to your virtual machine. The virtual machine should be powered off before you begin. If it is not, shut down the guest operating system normally, then click Power Off on the VMware Workstation toolbar.

Best jackjack